# How to get response from servlet to jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, response

I am trying get response from servlet use

```
request.setAttribute(error, error);
request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/redicted_test/Home.jsp").forward(request, response);

String redictedURL="http://localhost:8080/redicted_test/Home.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(redictedURL);
```

But get error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
```

Im understand that im send response twice, but how i can do it else? 
Can u tell me simplest way?

Comment: You dont have to explicitly redirect to Home.jsp. You have already  forwarded the request to Home.jsp, so it will respond to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have forwarded the request and now you are redirecting it

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/redicted_test/Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
..
response.sendRedirect(redictedURL);
```

If you want to set some attributes from servlet and need to display it on jsp, then just forward the request to jsp and display those attributes

Comment: U mean that use only getRequestDispatcher im get the parametrs in jsp and redict on this jsp?

Comment: Now i get description The requested resource (/zip_test/http:/localhost:8080/redicted_test/Home.jsp) is not available.

Comment: You need to give relative url to your jsp from your root web

Comment: Okey, now im use relative url see my jsp again. But this dont send any parametrs  in jsp i have if (request.getParameter("error")!=null)
  {
  out.write("alert("+request.getParameter("error")+")");
  }

Comment: it passes attributes not the parameter, you need to set the attributes in request, `request.setAttribute("key", "value"); ` before forwarding and then on jsp you can access it using JSTL `${key}`, See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: But how can i make alert in my jsp with ${key}?

Comment: by key I meant your attribute name that you have set from servlet

Comment: Maybe im have a syntax mistake in seting atribute?  error = "This is not zip archive";
   request.setAttribute("error", error);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: See this is the exact scenario:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info here it sets message attribute from sevlet and access from jsp

Comment: Im read this. Im do like in Hello World #2 (preprocess a request), but wihtout forEach tag. Im not see a syntax mistake.

Comment: Its work. Im change nothing just redeploy my project and no all fine, Tnx u. But i have a final question. How to not show a alert when page load in first time? I mean before servlet do his work? PS: my english is terrible.

Comment: well servlet after doing the work only sends the response so as I mentioned earlier it should work

Comment: In start of the page i see empty alert.

Comment: `alert('<c:out value="${key}">')`

Comment: anyway in alert i see c:out value=

Comment: it seems you missed to import taglib, please check the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info jsp part

Comment: import taglib and get error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: well that is whole new question, you should accept this one once you get this fixed, by the way for current issue http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/04/24/how-to-reference-and-use-jstl-in-your-web-application/

Comment: Glad it helped you after long discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have executed the jsp and the rendered jsp was sent in the response buffer. And since you have started to send the response, the response headers were sent. But just after that you wanted to send redirection and a redirection is a kind of headers manipulation (changes http status code and location headers).

Comment: Yes. Im delete response.sendRedirect(redictedURL);
But now servlet dont see jsp.

Comment: you can find a good explanation here http://www.roseindia.net/help/java/s/forward-vs-redirect.shtml

Answer (score 0):

After a `RequestDispatcher.forward()`, the response will be committed and closed. You cannot write any header/content to the response.

That is why you cannot `redirect` or `do operation which adds header or response content` after doing `RequestDispatcher.forward()`.

The alternative you have is use include instead of forward.

But, i did not understand your use case. You are forwarding and redirecting to the same page.